# I Got 304 error when I tried to fetch my localhost ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

I just create an ASP.NET Core Web API with react template.

I wrote this code

```
let options = {
   method: 'GET'
}

const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44482/WeatherForecast/Get", options);
```

But when I started my app I get an error

> 304 Not Modified

And this page in the response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>My App</title>
  <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What did I wrong?

I didn't change `program.cs` and routing in controllers.

I also got the same error in Postman

This is my Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
{
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

And this is my Programm.cs

```
using GoalJourney.Data;
using GoalJourney.Services;
using GoalJourney.Services.Interfaces;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IGoalService, GoalService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GoalDataContext>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: 304 isn't an error code, however you should post the API code because that is where the issue is. You have confirmed this by recreating the issue with Postman so well done, but now we need to see the code to make sure you are returning data in the response

Comment: Include your Endpoint Code will help ...

Comment: sure, I updated

Comment: If it is only Web API project then you don't need `AddControllersWithViews`, use `AddControllers()`. Are you sure that it is Web API? Or maybe you need MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolving this problem I separated site and web api part.

I made a new web api project and moved controllers, models and other servrers stuff.

I also fixed CORS problem, becouse I will do fetch from localhost:44482 to localhost:7005.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy( "AllowAll",
        policy  =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```